# Laravel 5.1 - No supported encrypter found error found when started

Tags: laravel-5.1

I got below error when I try to run my Laravel 5.1 application.

*"No supported encrypter found. The cipher and / or key length are invalid."*

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem by running below command:

```
php artisan key:generate
```